# Asking for peer review of theses innosetup snippets

Tags: delphi

To fullfil a promise, I cooked the following script :

```
[Code]
var
  BDS: string; // No trailing backslash path
  BDSCOMMONDIR: string; // No trailing backslash path
  BDSPROJECTSDIR: string; // No trailing backslash path
  BDSUSERDIR: string; // No trailing backslash path
  //
  BPLPath: string; // No trailing backslash path
  DCPPath: string; // No trailing backslash path
  //
  SearchPath: string; // Path list
  BrowsingPath: string; // Path list

function ExpandBdsEnvVar(s: string): string;
begin
  if Pos('$(BDS)', s) <> 0 then result := BDS + Copy(s,5+1,Length(s)-5)
  else if Pos('$(BDSCOMMONDIR)', s) <> 0 then result := BDSCOMMONDIR + Copy(s,15+1,Length(s)-15)
  else if Pos('$(BDSPROJECTSDIR)', s) <> 0 then result := BDSPROJECTSDIR + Copy(s,17+1,Length(s)-17)
  else if Pos('$(BDSUSERDIR)', s) <> 0 then result := BDSUSERDIR + Copy(s,12+1,Length(s)-12)
  else if Pos('$(HOMEPATH)', s) <> 0 then result := ExpandConstant('{userdesktop}') + Copy(s,11+1,Length(s)-11)
  else if Pos('$(DELPHI)', s) <> 0 then result := BDS + Copy(s,9+1,Length(s)-9)
  else result := s;
end;

function ReadBPL(s: string): string;
begin
  result := ExpandBdsEnvVar(BPLPath + Trim(s)); // Here comes the expansion for IS's sake !
end;

function CheckAndAppendPath(PathList: string; PathToCheck: string):string;
begin
  result := PathList;
  if (Pos(PathToCheck, PathList) = 0) then // Avoid duplicate append
    result := result + ';' + Trim(PathToCheck);
end;

function ReadDCP(s: string): string;
begin
  result := ExpandBdsEnvVar(DCPPath + Trim(s)); // Here comes the expansion for IS's sake !
end;

function ReadSearchPath(s: string): string;
begin
  result := CheckAndAppendPath(SearchPath,s) // Here comes the expansion for IS's sake !
end;

function ReadBrowsingPath(s: string): string;
begin
  result := CheckAndAppendPath(BrowsingPath,s)
end;
```

My intent is to use them as workaround to the lack of features stated above such as :

```
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  spath: String;
begin
  result := false;
  // $(BDS)\bin\bds.exe Check
  RegQueryStringValue(HKCU,'SOFTWARE\CodeGear\BDS\7.0','RootDir', spath);
  if FileExists(spath+'\bin\bds.exe') then
    begin
      BDS := RemoveBackslash(spath);
      // $(BDSCOMMONDIR) Check
      spath := AddBackslash(ExpandConstant('{commondocs}'))+'RAD Studio\7.0'; // No trailing backslash
      if DirExists(spath) then
        begin
          BDSCOMMONDIR := spath;
          //
          BDSPROJECTSDIR:=AddBackslash(ExpandConstant('{userdocs}'))+'RAD Studio\Projects'; // Assume it exists, no trailing backslash
          BDSUSERDIR:=AddBackslash(ExpandConstant('{userdocs}'))+'RAD Studio\7.0'; // Assume it exists, no trailing backslash
          // Search Path Check
          if RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, 'SOFTWARE\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\Library', 'Search Path', sPath) then
            begin
              SearchPath := RemoveBackslash(Trim(spath)); // No trailing backslash
              // Browsing Path Check
              if RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, 'SOFTWARE\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\Library', 'Browsing Path', sPath) then
                begin
                  BrowsingPath := RemoveBackslash(Trim(spath)); // No trailing backslash
                  // Package DPL Output Check
                  if RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, 'SOFTWARE\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\Library', 'Package DPL Output', spath) then
                    begin
                      BPLPath := RemoveBackslash(Trim(spath));  // No trailing backslash, no expansion for any $(...)
                      // Package DCP Output Check
                      if RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, 'SOFTWARE\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\Library', 'Package DCP Output', spath) then
                        begin
                          DCPPath := RemoveBackslash(Trim(spath));  // No trailing backslash, no expansion for any $(...)
                          //
                          result := true; // Boooooooooooooom, blast it !
                        end
                      else
                        MsgBox(cRegistryCorrMsg, mbError, MB_OK); // No "Package DCP Output" entry in the Registry
                    end
                  else
                    MsgBox(cRegistryCorrMsg, mbError, MB_OK); // No "Package DPL Output" entry in the Registry
                end
              else
                MsgBox(cRegistryCorrMsg, mbError, MB_OK); // No "Browsing Path" entry in the Registry
            end
          else
            MsgBox(cRegistryCorrMsg, mbError, MB_OK); // No "Search Path" entry in the Registry
        end
      else
        MsgBox(cCheckInstallMsg, mbError, MB_OK); // $(BDSCOMMONDIR) not found
    end
  else
    MsgBox(cCheckInstallMsg, mbError, MB_OK); // $(BDS)\bin\bds.exe not found
...
```

Is this approach acceptable ?

Any improvement are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Some generic notes below. (I'm not sure that the codes are valid Delphi codes or not. Feel free to fix them.)

Instead of `Copy(s,15+1,Length(s)-15)` you should create a function like this:

```
function ReplaceLastChars(input: string, charNum: integer): string;
begin
    // some input check should be here
    // for example: negative charNum probably is not allowed
    result := Copy(input, charNum + 1, Length(input) - charNum);
end;
```

It removes some data and code duplication.

Maybe you could change lines like

```
if Pos('$(BDSCOMMONDIR)', s) <> 0 then 
    result := BDSCOMMONDIR + Copy(s,15+1,Length(s)-15)
```

to a custom function:

```
function ChangeIfFound(input: string, pattern: string, replacement: string): string;
begin
    if Pos(pattern, input) <> 0 then 
        result := replacement + ReplaceLastChars(input, Length(pattern));
    else 
        result := input;
end;
```

then call it:

```
s := ChangeIfFound(s, '$(BDS)', BDS);
s := ChangeIfFound(s, '$(BDSCOMMONDIR)', BDSCOMMONDIR);
...
```

It's a little bit different from your original logic since it replaces all matches not just the first one. Maybe it's not appropriate for you.

If `StringReplace` exists in Delphi it could be more simple:

```
s := StringReplace(s, '$(BDS)', BDS);
s := StringRepace(s, '$(BDSCOMMONDIR)', BDSCOMMONDIR);
...
```

A possible bug: What happens when the `$(...)` string isn't at the beginning of the input string? Maybe you want to change

```
if Pos('$(BDS)', s) <> 0
```

to

```
if Pos('$(BDS)', s) = 1
```

or you should handle other return values of `Pos` too.

Comment: it's not Delphi code, it's pascal script used by Innoset wich is written under Delphi : Just a subset of Object Pascal.